# How to add Payment integration for iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, applepay

I am developing an iOS application in swift, In this application, User can buy the event photos by adding selected photos to cart. Here, How can i proceed with the payment options and do i need to add Apple Pay or In App-Purchase in this scenario?

I've done some research on this topic and I came to know.
 Apple Pay: Sells physical goods such as groceries, clothing, and appliances.

In-App: Sells virtual goods such as premium content for your app, and subscriptions for digital content.

So, in my application i am thinking about to add In-app purchase. Please confirm me? and help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have a look https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rock Balbao, Please confirm me whether using in app-purchase is correct in my application or is there a possibility to use apple pay?

Comment: follow the tutorial you will get [this](https://unsee.cc/mepaduzo/)

Comment: Ok sure, I will go through it. Thanks

Comment: It will give you what you should do and what not. So you'll have exact idea what to implement.  see this [image](http://imgur.com/a/ELQWb)

Comment: Ok thanks @RockBalbao

Comment: Is the photo delivered in your app or is a physical photo delivered outside your app?  In the first case you must use in-app purchase. In the second case you cannot use in-app purchase and you can use ApplePay or another payment solution.

Comment: After payment is done, we will provide some link to user. In that link he can save the photos. @Paulw11

Comment: you can use apple pay for the payment it will be less costlier for the merchant side

Comment: Are you sure apple will accept that in Appstore if we use Apple pay? Please note that we are going to sell photos in our application.@iOSDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to in-App purchase only for digital content-selling. Go with in-app purchase. If you are new to in-app purchase, here is the link to follow.

[Implementation of in-app purchase](http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sivajee , Can you please suggest me which payment integration is simple and easy? We are planning to add Authorize.net payment gateway.

Comment: Please don't use any other kind of payment gateways. That results in rejection of your app in appstore. Apple is strict on this rule. The only payment gateway to sell digital content should be apple in-app purchase

Comment: are you sure about that @SivajeeBattina

Comment: Yes. AFAIK I'm sure about this.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this works if i add Authorize.net payment. Is it possible to do that in my scenario?

Comment: I have good experience in this. From the scenarios I have seen so far, apple is rejecting if you don't use in-app purchase for digital content selling. I never see a situation where apple accepted any other payment gateway for this.

Comment: Ok but how the payment works in In-App? We dont need to add any other payment integrations? Please give me the info. @SivajeeBattina

Comment: First you need to create product identifier and set price for it. If user clicks on product you need to call methods to purchase item related to product identifier. You cannot use dynamic prices this way. You need to set differet price tiers realtes to product identifiers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022851/how-to-impliment-ios-in-app-purchase-for-books-with-dynamic-price this is the link that might answer your questions

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is there a possibility that we can add Apple Pay for payment? @SivajeeBattina

Comment: Apple pay only for physical goods bro ;-) I don't think apple will accept it.

Comment: FYI, Authorize.net payment gateway can be used as replacement for Apple pay but not for in-app purchases AFAIK

Comment: Hi Sivajee, Is there a possibility for adding Apple pay in app and testing sandbox account without apple developer account? Please let me know if you know regarding Apple Pay. Thanks @SivajeeBattina

Comment: You cannot create sandbox account without apple developer account. Here is the confirmation link: https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/

Comment: Thanks you so much for the info.